# Memory leak related to Slick

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, slick

I have a memory leak on my application, and I believe it's related to my Database connexion.
I'm using Scala 2.12.8 and Slick 3.3.2.

I dumped the memory of the JVM and tried to analyse it.
I have a lot of `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` with inside it SSL related objects with the URL of my MySQL database.

[Screenshot of the Finalizer in the memory dump analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtODX.png)

It's seems that I've done something wrong with the database connexion.

```
class SlickDbContext extends DbContext {
  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SlickDbContext")
  private val minDbThreads = 10
  private val maxDbThreads = 10
  private val maxDbConnexions = 100

  logger.info("Initializing Db Context")

  private val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  private val db = Database.forURL(
    url = conf.getString("db.url"),
    user = conf.getString("db.user"),
    password = conf.getDecryptedString("db.password"),
    driver = conf.getString("db.driver"),
    executor = AsyncExecutor("dbExecutor", minDbThreads, maxDbThreads, maxDbConnexions))

  db.createSession()

  def query[T](queryFunc: DbAction[T]): Future[T] = db.run(queryFunc)

  def transact[T](queryFunc: DbAction[T]): Future[T] = db.run(queryFunc.transactionally)
}
```

I also tried to use, or not use, a custom executor but nothing changed

Does anyone know where this memory leak could come from?
Thanks.

[Edit] I should precise that this class is instanciated only one time

Comment: it happens to me similar using MySql + play-slick + play-framework 2.7.x and I don't manage to release the same with any garbage collector